# Unity PlayerPrefs is not updating my 'high score'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game where you're in the middle of the screen and you move round an endless green (screen) world and white cubes spawn randomly around you, and I have finished the game mechanics and a main menu and game over screens. The one thing I'm trying to add now is a high score. I did a bit of research and found `PlayerPrefs` is probably the way to do it. I have a seperate scene for my main menu and my gameplay level (which includes the game over screen). I have no error messages. I have created a `HSSetter` (High Score Setter) script on the high score text in the main menu screen:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HSSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text highScoreText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore").ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore").ToString();
    }
}
```

and in my `score` script which is in my actual game level, here's the bit where I try to create the high score:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int scoreCount = 0;

    public int highScoreIFA;

    
    void Start()
    {
        highScoreIFA = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (scoreCount >= highScoreIFA)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", scoreCount);
        }
    }


    public void AddToScore()
    {
        if (isHit == true) // i know this if loop works
        {
            scoreCount += 1; // and this, I use it to change the score text in-game.
            isHit = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In `AddToScore()`, I increment `scoreCount`.

Through some debugging, I have found that everything in the `HSSetter` script works - when I change the `highScoreText.text`, the text on screen changes, which led me to believe the issue might be with the change of scenes? Thanks!

Comment: What *should* happen when `highScoreIFA` is 1 and `scoreCount` is 2? What *actually* happens in `Update`?

Comment: Let's say on `Start` your `HighScore` is 50, now `scoreCount` is 0.  So You will set your int CONSTANTLY until `scoreCount` is greater than `highScoreIFA`.  Get it, your `if` logic is backwards.

Comment: ah ok @jiveturkey , but surely this would just set my 'high score' on the main menu to whatever my most recent score was, not just `0` the whole time, which it does? I'll edit my post now to switch `highScoreIFA` and `scoreCount`.

Comment: Where are you incrementing `scoreCount`?  I'm sure you are somewhere.

Comment: @jiveturkey , I have a boolean, `isHit`, which I know works here as it adds to `scoreCount` correctly: I am now editing my post to include the incrementation of `scoreCount`, and thanks for answering! Edit: also, I call the function `AddToScore` from a separate script, which I know works.

Comment: That is where you should put your `if (scoreCount >= highScoreIFA)` logic.  You definitely don't want to be checking and possibly updating every frame.

Comment: Since you've changed your if logic does it work?  The way you had it before would definitely explain why it was always 0.

Comment: @jiveturkey thanks so much! It works now! I'll now go and put the `if` statement in the `AddToScore()` function. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things you should do here

- The first you already updated in your question afterwards: You had the condition wrong and always updated only

  ```
   if(highScoreIFA > scoreCount)
  ```

  which would almost always be the case.

  Now you have changed it to

  ```
   if(scoreCount >= highScoreIFA)
  ```

  which still is not good since if the score is equal there is no reason to update it, yet.

  I would rather use

  ```
   if(scoreCount > highScoreIFA)
  ```

  so only really update it when needed.
- Secondly in both scripts do not use `Update` **at all**! That is extremely inefficient.

  I would rather use event driven approach and only change and set stuff in the one single moment it actually happens.
- You should only one single class (e.g. the `score`) be responsible and allowed to read and write the `PlayerPrefs` for this. I know lot of people tent to use the `PlayerPrefs` for quick and dirty cross access to variables. But it is exactly this: Quick but very dirty and error prone.

  If you change the keyname in the future you'll have to do it in multiple scripts.

  Instead rather let only the `score` do it but then let other scripts reference it and retrieve the values directly from that script instead
- And finally you should use

  ```
  PlayerPrefs.Save();
  ```

  to create checkpoints. It is automatically done in `OnApplicationQuit`, bit in case your app is force closed or crashes the User would lose progress ;)

Might look like

```
public class score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int scoreCount = 0;

    // Use an event so every other script that is interested
    // can just register callbacks to this
    public event Action<int> onHighScoreChanged;

    // Use a property that simply always invoked the event whenever 
    // the value of the backing field is changed
    public int highScoreIFA
    {
        get => _highScoreIFA;
        set
        {
            _highScoreIFA = value;
            onHighScoreChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }

    // backing field for the public property
    private int _highScoreIFA;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        highScoreIFA = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
    }

    public void AddToScore()
    {
        if (isHit == true) // i know this if loop works
        {
            scoreCount += 1; // and this, I use it to change the score text in-game.
            isHit = false;

            // Only update the Highscore if it is greater
            // not greater or equal
            if (scoreCount > highScoreIFA)
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", scoreCount);
                // Save is called automatically in OnApplicationQuit
                // On certain checkpoints you should call it anyway to avoid data loss 
                // in case the app is force closed or crashes for some reason
                PlayerPrefs.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your other script only listens to the event and updates its display accordingly. It is even questionable if both scripts should not rather simply be one ;)

```
public class HSSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text highScoreText;

    // Reference your Score script here
    [SerializeField] private score _score;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // Find it on runtime as fallback
        if(!_score) _score = FindObjectOfType<score>();

        // Register a callback to be invoked everytime there is a new Highscore
        // Including the loaded one from Start
        _score.onHighScoreChanged += OnHighScoreChanged;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _score.onHighScoreChanged += OnHighScoreChanged;
    }

    private void OnHighScoreChanged(int newHighScore)
    {
        highScoreText.text = $"High Score: {newHighScore}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take on board some of these.